# Can I copy an SE profile to overwrite all my blank profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page

A few of my SE accounts have the “about me” section filled in. The majority, however, leave it blank, because I could think of nothing to say. Now I’ve thought of some generic text I could apply to all sites, but there’s no obvious way to copy a profile to all **blank** SE accounts. The only option is to copy to **all** SE accounts, which would overwrite the ones which already have a custom “about me” section. I don’t want to do that.

I just want to copy the “about me” text. If that requires copying everything else too, that’s okay.

Maybe there’s already a way to do this, but if so, I can’t find it.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the good ol' copy and paste may be the only way. (I could be wrong though).

Comment: Ah well. This'd be a nice-to-have, not particularly important.

Comment: How many accounts are we talking about?

Comment: Er. Quite a lot. I tend to create an account on every SE site I come across.

Comment: @Yosi, well, according to his profile, 94 accounts

Comment: @TRiG I agree, I am sure someone has made or can make a workaround that would do this.

Comment: +1 - that's some work to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option for this. However, I have a tip to optimize the amount of work you have to do:

If the total number of blank profiles is greater than the total number of filled profiles, then copy to all profiles and re-fill the already filled ones.

If the total number of blank profiles is less than the total number of filled profiles, just copy your information to the blank profiles.